# i need to update the list immediately, once data is deleted in angular 13 component

Tags: angular, web, crud, angular13

I am deleting an object from the component, and i need to update the list immediately once the object is deleted, without refreshing the page.
component.ts

```
deleteSource(id: any){
  if(confirm("Are you sure to delete?")){
  console.log(id)
    this.sourcesService.deleteSource(id).subscribe();
    }
    }
```

service.ts

```
 deleteSource(id: string): Observable<number>{

     return this.http.delete<number>(this.API_URL +id);
  }
```

component.html

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="deleteSource(source.id)" style="margin-left:5px">
```

Comment: Get the list of values after deleting, call it inside the subscribe method

Comment: You're welcome do close the ticket by answering your own question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just had to call get again in the subscribe

```
this.sourcesService.deleteSource(id).subscribe(source =>  this.Source());
```

Answer (score 0):

even though the question has already been answered, I just want to complete it

```
this.sourcesService.deleteSource(id).pipe(switchMap(_ => this.Source()).subscribe();
```

In this specific case there won't be an issue with the amount of requests since the user has to accept a dialog, but if this was a button that can be clicked many times on delete, you would have multiple unnecessary calls to the backend, with [switchMap](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/switchMap) you would end up canceling the ones that are no longer needed.